# Midpoint Ellipse Algorithm vs Midpoint Circle Algorithm

Tags: graphics, geometry, ellipse, bresenham

I have the Midpoint Ellipse drawing Algorithm and I have the Midpoint Circle drawing Algorithm.

Why do I need a separate algorithm for drawing circles, when I can just use the Ellipse midpoint algorithm for drawing a circle simply by specifying the radii along both axes to be of equal length?

Comment: Do you realize that circles can use 8-way symmetry but ellipses use 4-way?  You basically do half the arithmetic to draw a circle, compared to an ellipse.  Is that all you need to know or is there a deeper question?  If the answer is "because you can optimize for the symmetry of a circle and it's faster" is that all you're looking for?

Comment: I thought of this when considering the answer. It is the main thing. But, I wanted to know if there is something other than just the optimization considerations? Because, in my case, I do not have to really bother about optimisations at this stage.

Comment: This slideshow has those kinds of answers: https://slideplayer.com/slide/8478463/  "Is there something other than just the optimization considerations" is too broad.  Surely there are nuances to keep academics interested for years.  I don't expect that I'll ever need to know what those nuances are.  If *you* are interested in a specific nuance, then let us know what it is.  If you don't care about optimization, then you probably just appreciate the increased flexibility of the ellipse algorithm.  I don't think there's any more to it than that.

Comment: Yep. I think this answers it sufficiently enough for me. I don't have a particular nuance in mind. Thank you !!